# How do I add a certain number each time when click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `var i = 14`, and button that increment `i++`.

When I click on the button I have added every time +1.
Example 14, 15, 16, 17.

I want to do step not in with 1 but with  14. Example 14, 28, 42?

https://jsfiddle.net/xLwDgZODc/zkont5d4/

```js
var i = 14;

$('.click').click(function() {
  $('.result').text(i++);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class='result'></span>
<button class="click">Click</button>
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the wanted value to the variable.

```
var i = 14;

$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.result').text(i += 14);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an alternative option, you could use `<input type="number" />` as it offers exactly the functionality you want using the `step` attribute:

```html
<input type="number" value="14" step="14" />
```

Then, if you want a variable that is updated with every increase/decrease, just add an `eventListener`:

```js
var i;

stepper.addEventListener('input', () => { i = result.textContent = stepper.value; console.log(i); })
```

```html
<input type="number" value="14" step="14" id="stepper" />
<span id="result">14</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to increase the `i` variable by +1 each time until it's higher or equal to `14` then it starts to increase by +14.
Here is a script that i've made for your problem, hope you enjoy it!

```js
var i = 0;

$('.click').click(function() {
  i < 14 ? i++ : i += 14;
  $("#counter").text(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="counter">0</span>
<button class="click">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add your step to i , see below fiddle :

```js
var i = 14;
var step = 14;

$('.click').click(function() {
  $('.result').text(i);
     i += step;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">click</button><br />
Result :<div class="result">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 14;

$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.result').text(i += 14);
});
//Since your increment is by 14 i+=14
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!